# Different Record Page for View / Edit - (No Visualforce)

Tags: flexipages

Is possible to create **2 Record Pages**, and show one for the **Edit** form view, and the other for the **detail record view** ?

We need to show different list of fields on edition than on record detail view.

I know there are a lot of other similar questions. And the common answers are: RecordType or Visualforce Action overides. But they dont address this need.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can combine action overrides with record types to achieve this effect. The action override simply calls the edit page with the new record type selected. A trigger or automation changes the record type back to the view mode when saving. Alternatively, on the detail page, you could just create a component to show the fields, while leaving the edit page alone. Note that any of these approaches have limitations anyways. It likely won't feel as good as the native UI. What you're asking for isn't a configuration-only feature.

Comment: Thank you Brian, coming from you I will take this as very True. 
Will see if this workaround-hack worth for the UX we are looking for. 
It is strange to me that SF hasn't included yet this "simple" option for LEX